# Objective C: Send email without leaving app

Tags: objective-c, email, ios

How do I send an email within an app without leaving the app.

This works:

```
-(void) sendEmailTo:(NSString *)to withSubject:(NSString *)subject withBody:(NSString *)body {
NSString *mailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?to=%@&subject=%@&body=%@",
                        [to stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                        [subject stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                        [body stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mailString]];
}
```

but goes to the mail app to send. Is there a way to do this without leaving the app?

Comment: You may find [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-discussion/43633-quick-tutorial-how-add-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller.html) tutorial helpful.

Comment: I found [this](http://www.codingexplorer.com/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-send-email-in-your-apps/) tutorial better http://www.codingexplorer.com/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-send-email-in-your-apps/

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes. Use the [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
// From within your active view controller
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailCont setSubject:@"yo!"];
    [mailCont setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"joel@stackoverflow.com"]];
    [mailCont setMessageBody:@"Don't ever want to give you up" isHTML:NO];
    [self presentViewController:mailCont animated:YES completion:nil];

}


// Then implement the delegate method
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: This kind of worked, but it won't exact the mail screen when its done

Comment: You also need to implement the delegate method, which I added.

Comment: That second part goes in the implementation file as well, correct? Because it still freezes either when I hit cancel or send on the email screen

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to set the delegate, too.

Comment: the line mailCont.delegate = self;   
should read:
mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;

delegate is for the UINavigationController, of which the MFMailComposeViewController is a subclass.

Comment: Dont forget: #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

Comment: "[self presentModalViewController:mailCont animated:YES];" is depricated. Use, "[self presentViewController:mailCont animated:YES completion:nil];" and "[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];" also deprecated. Use, "[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];"

Answer (score 27):

1. Add MessageUI framework:

   - Click on the project
   - Select "Build Phases"
   - Expand "Link Binary With Libraries"
   - Click "+" and type "Message" to find "MessageUI" framework, then add.
2. In current view controller add import and implement a protocol:

   ```
   #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h> 
   #import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h> 
   @interface MyViewController : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
   ```

Add methods:

```
    -(void)sendEmail {
        // From within your active view controller
        if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
            MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;        // Required to invoke mailComposeController when send

            [mailCont setSubject:@"Email subject"];
            [mailCont setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"myFriends@email.com"]];
            [mailCont setMessageBody:@"Email message" isHTML:NO];

            [self presentViewController:mailCont animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }

    - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

Updated for iOS 6. Please note that this uses ARC and does not use the deprecated modal view presentation:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h> 
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h> 
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

And then the code to present the email screen:

```
- (IBAction)emailButtonPushed:(id)sender {

    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailCont setSubject:@"Your email"];
        [mailCont setMessageBody:[@"Your body for this message is " stringByAppendingString:@" this is awesome"] isHTML:NO];
        [self presentViewController:mailCont animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    //handle any error
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```