# how to send email from an app in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ipad, xcode4.2

i am creating an app when a user clicks contactUS button a UIAlertview will appear where it consists of name , email textfield , when user clicks send UIButton , i should get an email saying user wants to contact me and user should receive a email saying thank you for the email . I want to know how to do it ,any help would be helpful .

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862523/objective-c-send-email-without-leaving-app) help?

Comment: Not only is this a duplicate, it's also covered by official documentation and probably several tutorials already.

Comment: bazinga is just lazy to look for tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Apple's MailComposer example. This will show you everything you need. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008865

Comment: i'll check and let you know if i have any doubt .
can i want two emails to be send with different body and subject ..the user will get confirmation email and whereas i get his name ,email info so that i could contact him

Comment: No I don't think it will allow you to send 2 email out at once. You shouldn't do that if it does. You should setup an auto reply on your email server to send the conformation to the customer.

Comment: how to do auto reply on email server to send confirmation

Comment: i am new to ipad programming ,can u help me in steps

Comment: It would be difficult to give you step by step instructions on how to do either. If you download apple's sample Mail Composer, it will show you everything you need. For the Auto-Reply, it depends on who you use for email. Just google how to setup an auto-reply email. There are several different was to do it.

Comment: 1 )i downloaded the apple mail application code, i tried to send a message to my email but i didnt got it ..does the app work only when it is loaded on the device or should i do something else like network check 


2 )I want to change few things in code where i'll be adding name field ,email id textfield ,so when the user sends me email ,in the email his name and his email id should be displayed ,can u help me in these two points