# UITableView for mail contacts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email, uitableview

I've been looking all over and I probably just skipped over it but this is what i need.  I have a table view with a list of email addresses and i want a user to be able to choose one of those and have the mail composer view to pop up with that email address selected to be the recipient.  I cant find it.

Comment: Could you specify what your problem is please?

Comment: Chech `MFMailComposerViewController`

Comment: i know about the mfmailcompiserviewcontroller but what im trying to do is display email addresses on the uitableview and when the user taps on of the uitable cells it will be the email address in the mfmailcomposerviewcontroller

Comment: like you now how you go to your contacts app the view a contact and theres a cell with the email address.  If you tapped that email address it would open a composer view with that email address as the recipient

Comment: actually i figured it out, i could just use some custom cells

Comment: You would usually just get the text from the selected cell (which should be contained within a pre-defined array), the. Set it as the recipents property on an MFMailComposeViewController.

Answer (score 1):

That would probably do it:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //Get data from the datasource (supposing a one dimensional list)
    NSString *theRecipent=[[self dataSource] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]

    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailCont setSubject:@"The Subject"];
        [mailCont setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theRecipent]];
        [mailCont setMessageBody:@"I should elaborate more my questions :P" isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailCont animated:YES];
        [mailCont release];
    }
}
```

---

```
// The delegate method
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you have to use the `MFMailComposeViewController` class to send the email (it's always good to check that you can send the email) and send the email.

Some of the code was taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862523/objective-c-send-email-without-leaving-app).

Comment: Should better do this. 
Class mailClass = NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController");
    if (mailClass != nil) {
        if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
            
        }
    }

Comment: What would be the advantage of doing that? I'm in to learn stuff :D

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake. It is not necessary to do that, but It is better to check if ([[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]) return nil. If there is no mail account set up in the device, ([[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]) return nil on some device and App crashes, I met this kind of situation.

Comment: This is why people need to read before they ask simple questions like these.  I realize this now that I look back at my old questions