# Objective C: Send email with subject and body and switching app

Tags: objective-c, mailto, document-body, subject

I want to send eMails with subject and body.

This is my code right now and it works as expected. It´s leaving my app and creating a new message in Mail.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:wettbewerb@neunfornkunst.ch"]];
```

However, I want to create more complex messages including subject and body like this:
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:wettbewerb@neunfornkunst.ch?subject=my Subject?body=my Body"]];

Which does´t do anything at all as soon as I add the subject.
Any idea what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this out.

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mcvc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mcvc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    NSString *toAddress = //recepient_name_here;
    [mcvc setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:toAddress,nil]];
    [mcvc setSubject:subject];
    [mcvc setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [mcvc addAttachmentData:ifAny mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:fileName];
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I´m afraid I´m going to face new problems. At the moment I prefer the mailto solution. And in the meantime I found that I have to use %20 for space and %0D%0A for carriage return to get this working. Is it possible to switch to Mail to leave the control to the user?

Comment: After taking a closer look to your proposal it came out to be perfect for my needs, thanks a lot.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862523/objective-c-send-email-without-leaving-app